# Distinct values on filtered queryset and 'Q' operator

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views

I have these models:

```
class Event(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
[...]

class dateEvent(models.Model):

    event = models.ForeignKey('Event', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
[...]
```

and in my `views.py` I want to create a query which selects an event given specific parameters (start date, etc.). I have no issues with my query:

```
distinct = Event.objects.values('id').annotate(id_count=Count('id')).filter(id_count=1)
events = Event.objects.filter(Q(dateevent__start_date_time__gte=start_date) & Q(dateevent__start_date_time__lte=end_date))
```

This pulls up more ideantical results if there is more than one `dateevent` for each `event` though, which I don't want. This is my attempt of getting distinct values, which fails with a `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'Q'` error. what am I missing?

```
events = Event.objects.filter(id__in=[item['id'] for item in distinct]).Q(dateevent__start_date_time__lte=end_date).distinct().exclude(type='recording release').order_by('dateevent__start_date_time')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making this too complicated. You can work with [**`.distinct()`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct):

```
Event.objects.filter(
    dateevent__start_date_time__gte=start_date,
    dateevent__start_date_time__lte=end_date
).distinct()
```

You can not `.order_by(..)` on the related `dateEvent`s, since then you that will thus be part of the `SELECT ...` clause, and prevent the uniqness filter from working properly. You can however work with an aggregate over it. For example:

```
from django.db.models import Min

Event.objects.exclude(type='recording release').filter(
    dateevent__start_date_time__gte=start_date,
    dateevent__start_date_time__lte=end_date
).alias(
    first_event=Min('dateevent__start_date_time')
).order_by('first_event').distinct()
```

Comment: That's the first thing I did (although with the `Q` operator), and since it's not doing anything different then I went for the more complicated route. Even without the Q operator, as per your answer, I still gets duplicated events.

Comment: @HBMCS: This can not return the *same* `Event` twice. The `.distinct()` ensures that the primary key of two `Event`s in the queryset is different. So that means that either you have two `Event`s with the same name, etc.; or you somehow `.annotate(..)`/`.values(..)`/.. it and this thus passes extra data in the `SELECT` breaking the distinct part.

Comment: Thank you. The event is unique, I just checked. This is my full query `dateevent__start_date_time__lte=end_date).distinct().exclude(type='recording release').order_by('dateevent__start_date_time')`.

Comment: @HBMCS: ah, but you can not order on `dateevent__start_date_time`, since that will distinct it. Do you want to order it on the *first* `dateEvent`, or the *last* one?

Comment: I just tried with the `exclude()` taken out just in case, same thing.

Comment: @HBMCS: no, `.order_by(..)` is the culprit, see comment above.

Comment: Very good point! The `.order()` was invalidating the `distinct()` indeed, thanks. What if I wanted to order it by the first occurring`dateevent_start_date_time` then? Would that be possible?

Comment: @HBMCS: see edit: this will however order by the first one in the given time range, since we filter out the `dateEvent`s outside that time range.